# Gender specific pronouns

Tags: personal-pronouns

I noticed people using pronouns next to their names `Jo (she/her)`. I understand the reason behind the first part (she), but I completely don't get the second part. Doesn't "she" imply "her"? Is it even possible to use something else, "She changed his mind" (same person) - it wouldn't make sense (from the grammar perspective), would it?

So my question is: why the second part is there?

I understand this may be a delicate matter, I don't mean to offend, just trying to understand a grammatical (and possibly cultural) phenomenon.

Comment: It's just someone being clear about both the subject and object forms.  Not particularly necessary for "she", but if someone adopted "shis" and "shims" it would be quite helpful.

Comment: But what of possessive and reflexive forms? Would they not be equally ill-known for these invented personal pronouns? (I am shakily assuming that *shis* and *shims* are subject and object forms respectively.)

Comment: << Jo (she) >> is perhaps considered less intuitively interpretable as << Joe (a female) >> than << Jo (she/her) >>. Novel usages are almost always difficult. They tend to confuse or be unattractive / wordy.

Answer (score -1):

Purely grammatically speaking, there are actually **five** inflectional forms that would need to be supplied: nominative (***I***), accusative (***me***), dependent genitive (***my***), independent genitive (***mine***), and reflexive (***myself***). I have also observed that people normally supply two (e.g. *they/them*). Note that this is indeed incomplete: what, for example, is the reflexive form? Is it *themselves* or *themself*? However, people sometimes do supply more than two. For example, according to [this CNN report](https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/16/us/preferred-gender-pronouns-explainer-trnd/index.html),

> recently, Sen. Kamala Harris introduced herself at a CNN LGBTQ Town Hall by stating that her pronouns are “**she, her and hers.”**

I would speculate that the most common form of indicating the pronoun preference in writing,

> **(they/them)**
> **(she/her)**
> etc.

i.e. two inflectional forms separated by a slash and in parentheses, has become a way to signal—a code of sorts—that these are indeed the person's preferred pronouns without the person having to write out the full sentence *My preferred pronouns are…* After all, giving just one may be a bit confusing as to what it is supposed to mean. (EDIT: this is point 2. in [the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450584/155553) to the question linked above.)

**Discussion**

Further down in the CNN report, it says,

> The most common third-person singular pronouns are “she/her/hers” and “he/him/his.” “They/them” can also be used to refer to a single person, while some people use gender-neutral or gender-inclusive pronouns like “ze/hir” (pronounced zee/here) instead. Some people might not use pronouns at all and go only by a name.

Here is the 'traditional' list of first-person pronouns. The categories are NOMINATIVE, ACCUSATIVE, DEPENDENT GENITIVE, INDEPENDENT GENITIVE, and REFLEXIVE ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 327):

DEP     IND
NOM    ACC    GEN    GEN     REF
    I          me      my      mine    myself
    he       him    his        his       himself
    she     her     her       hers     herself

Here are five sample sentences, illustrating the use of these five inflectional forms:

NOM:           ***I** go to work.*
ACC              *Words can't hurt **me**.*
DEP GEN:  *That's **my** umbrella.*
IND GEN:  *That umbrella is **mine***
REF:            *I may hurt **myself**.*

Here are some gender-neutral third-person singular pronouns that have been proposed [(source)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210114143532/https://uwm.edu/lgbtrc/support/gender-pronouns/):

they them their theirs themself
(f)ae (f)aer (f)aer (f)aers (f)aerself
per per pers pers pserself
xe xem xyr xyrs xenself
ze/zie hir hir hirs hirself
zie     zim     zir     zis     zieself
sie     sie     hir     hirs    hirself
ey  em  eir     eirs    eirself
ve  ver     vis     vis/vers    verself
tey     ter     tem     ters    terself
e/ey    em  eir     eirs    emself/eirself